# Emoticon keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm developing a simple emoticon keyboard on android,

I want to use this keyboard on any application. when the user click on any displayed emoticon it must appear on the screan

My question what is the best way to post emoticons images between two mobiles .. It doesn't make sense to send them as image. I tried to send them as font .. but the problem was that it is only appeared in black color ,,, so, what is the solution?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts

Answer (score 0):

Consider two phones:
A & B

Install the images  for these emoticons in the phones and each image would have an id. When the user at phone A presses the key for say ":-)" .. pass the id that refers to that particular emoticon to phone B and use it to refer to the exact emoticon. Hope it helped

Comment: This would only work if both phones where running the same application. Further, it's not cross platform.